# Shell script not parsing “-n” as an argument

Tags: bash

I have a shell script that contains just

```
echo $1
```

when i run

```
script.sh -d
```

it outputs `-d`, and it does the same for every other letter.

but when i try

```
script.sh -n
```

it doesn’t print `-n`. what might be the problem?

I expect it to print `-n` but it doesn’t do that

Comment: Try manually running `echo -n`, then read the fine manual

Comment: You should see the same behavior (ie, no output) for `-e` and `-E`, too; check the man pages or online help and you'll find that `echo` has (at least) 3 hyphenated flags ... `-n`, `-e` and `-E` so when those are passed to `echo` they are treated as a flag to `echo` and *not* as an argument

Comment: Also see [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29378566/4154375), [Bash Pitfalls #14 (echo $foo)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo), and [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).